# How do I resolve this error with add_shortcode and wpdb on in functions.php on my Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, addition, shortcode

I'm writing a function that I want to call from a shortcode and return the name of a user from their ID. I have added this code into my functions.php file.

```
function get_name_result() { 
global $wpdb;
$dbresult = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT name FROM person WHERE id = 2",OBJECT);
return $dbresult;
}

add_shortcode('get_name', 'get_name_result');
?>
```

[person table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oQri.png)

When placed on a page, the shortcode returns "array" rather than 'Jim'. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: get_var instead of get_results? or return $dbresult[0];

Comment: you need to return $dbresult->name;

please print_r($dbresult); so I can tell you what to return exactly.

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Jim ) )

Comment: If I swap return $dbresult; for return $dbresult->name; I get no result

Comment: I'm afraid neither get_var or return $dbresult[0] work either

Comment: Sorry didn't tag @OliverMGrech in my earlier reply

Comment: try $dbresult[0]->name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect only 1 record (assuming so since you are using an id in your where statement) you can return it with

return $dbresult[0]->name;